# How to calculate subtraction of two fields and keep that ans in third fields in mysql in same table?

Tags: mysql

I have three fileds namely num1 num2 and num3/ans i wanted to a subtract the num1 and num2 filed and ans should be there in num3/ans field  for ex num1 value is 400 and num value is 100 then the value in ans/num3 field should be there automatically

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this?

```
UPDATE tbl
SET num3 = num1 - num2
```

or if you want calculated field, it is impossible directly,but you can use trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.num3 = NEW.num1 - NEW.num2;
```